# How to wait till data is assigned to model in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, model, angular-promise, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a model which I use to iterate and create a tabular structure on my view. I have a button on click of which I have to get the latest value from DB and assign to model. Then I get the innerHTML of model and create a pdf of my current view.

I am facing a issue that before the data is completely assigned to model and view is refreshed the next statement to get the innerHTML of container div executes and I get the older snapshot of my view. How can I hold the execution of my statement until model is done with assignment and view has refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your code in `$timeout`. This will make sure that your code is executed in the next cycle and you will get the latest snapshot.

```
$timeout(function(){
   <your code to get innerHtml>
})
```

There is no need to mention any timeout value as this will be called once view has changed

PS: Add `$timeout` as dependency.

Comment: i am not sure how much of time gap would be sufficient for this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: you don't need to give any time for this. This timeout will be executed after view has refreshed.

Comment: thanks ashfaq but as far as i know empty $timeout does the job for us, it will trigger digest cycle but it doesnot guarantee if the data assignment to model has finished.

Comment: you are mistaken Vishal. Timeout guarantee that the view will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ng-show from angular and display your content only when the data is loaded in the controller:

```
HTML:
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="getValues()">
 <div ng-show="dataLoaded">
  <input type="number" ng-repeat="(key, value) in randomArray track by  $index" ng-model="randomArray[key]">

 </div>
</div>


CONTROLLER:
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.getValues = function() {

    $scope.randomArray = ['myKey', 'anotherKey', 'thirdKey', 'key4'];    
    angular.forEach($scope.randomArray, function(value, key){
      $scope.randomArray[key] = 0;
    });

    // Set dataLoaded to true
   $scope.dataLoaded = true;
  }

});
```

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/KrmgNL?editors=1011

Comment: Hi gianni. what if :statement ' $scope.dataLoaded = true;' is executed before the angular for each finishes. That is what i need. In your case the data is small but in case of huge data the synchronous execution breaks the code.

Comment: You need to use  promise then, your function will be executed only after data is loaded. Check out this codePen: http://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/akWGRp?editors=1011